# Trying to get metadata of tracks in spotify

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

currently I try to get metadata of tracks in spotify using the python library spotipy. Has anyone any idea if there is already an existing app? To specify my problem I wanna know how often a track was streamed with spotify. I searched the internet for it but havent found anything...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. I looked into the Spotify web API, could not find track plays so I found this on google

[Return track play count from Get a Track Request #70](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/70)

You could also look into [popularity](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/object-model/#track-object-full)